# Get all taxonomy posts by id

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I have this code that should return all the posts that related to the taxonomy id, but it returns the last 5 posts.

```
<?php 
$leaderships = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'      => 'posttype',
    'posts_per_page' => 11,
    'tax_query'      => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy-name', 
            'field'    => 'id',
            'terms'    => 13,
        ),
    ),
));
?>
```

posts_per_page is not working here, Any help to get all the posts.

Thanks

Comment: Can you confirm that you have more than 5 posts assosiated with this taxonomy?

Comment: I have 7 posts, and when I create a new one it shows first but a one from the 5 is hidden instead. so one added then one hidden.

Comment: do you have any theme code or plugins which may be modifying the query? test by disabling plugins, use default theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks every one for help, I discovered that that the problem is from my theme admin that was limiting the posts to 5 and fixed now.